# Learn Appcelerator Titanium Programming

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Can anyone help me for getting all basic controls programming knowledge in development for appcelerator titanium for iphone? if u have any basic tutorial please send me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Titanium, any newly-created app automatically compiles into a "hello world" without any programming at all. After that, you can supposedly download what's called the "kitchen sink", but I gave up on Titanium before reaching that part :^)

Comment: i appreciate your quick reply but my can you tell me that how can i do it so it help me lot. again thanks for you help

Comment: yes and i start to learn about it..

Answer (score 0):

Run sample 3-4 application which is provided with titanium studio like Kitchensink,RSSReader etc and learn how its coded.
For more info,goto
http://www.appcelerator.com
http://docs.appcelerator.com

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer little bit more?